# Kendo UI Type Script Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have installed latest type definition file of Kendo UI from package manager console and include the file in type script as :

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/kendo-ui/kendo-ui.d.ts" />
```

Also i have tried to install previous versions but getting the same issue :

```
drillDownDataSource: any = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: 'StatutoryIncome/GetStatutoryIncomeStatementView/',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                cache: true,
                autoBind: true, // This property is not accessible 
                data: function() {},
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {
                            models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

As i mentioned in above code autobind property is not accessible, even if i remove the **auto-bind** property the **parameterMap** function gives error.
Also the functions of **kendoTreelist** like **content** is not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [KendoUI docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap), `parameterMap` should be nested under `transport` not under `transport.read`.

And as far as I'm aware `autobind` does not exist in the `DataSource` configuration, this config-element is usually available on the component itself. (See for example the [TreeList-Configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#configuration-autoBind))